# Как убрать scroll bar при создание параллакс эффекта?

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в следующей задаче.
Пытаюсь создать параллакс эффект на css. Вроде бы все удалось достичь, одна появляется дополнительный скролл. Нашел в сети что его можно убрать с помощью такого куска кода

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
```

Действительно помогло, однако не могу понять, как сброс отступов убирает скролл? Кто-то может объяснить данный момент?
Также есть второй момент, при добавлении в код еще контента, снова появляется скролл.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wraper {
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

.content::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/560b24bae099abf1bacdbafb162d62b2.jpg);
  /*background-color: #f10000;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.content h1 {
  /*margin-top: 400px;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>заголовок</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wraper">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>заголовок</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если в данном коде раскомментировать дополнительный контент появится скролл.
Добавление тегу `html` свойств `overflow:hidden`, не помогает так как перестает скролится остальная страница.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно скрыть скролл, чтобы остался эффект параллакс и если кто знает, подскажите по первому вопросу( про сброс отступов).
Заранее огромное всем спасибо

Comment: да. то что на тостере мне не подходит. я писал про то что html добавить overflow:hidden не подходит и там нет ни какого параллакса, просто зафиксированный блок.

Comment: Ты лучше в вопросе опиши чего хочешь добиться, так сказать окончательные результат.

Comment: https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw вот так ?

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0px; display: none; }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Добавьте описание к коду ответа

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте скрыть scrollbar при помощи css. Подробное [описание тут](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp).

Для этого можно использовать псевдоэлемент *-webkit-scrollbar* :

Есть исключения, не поддерживаются ***Mozilla Firefox***

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: В `FF` не поддерживает

Comment: Ярослав, большое спасибо за совет, но насколько я понимаю, это решение не кроссбраузерное. но все равно спасибо